# Yii2 - How to pass 'isNewRecord' to custom form?

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, model, yii2

I have a custom form `CreateAdminForm` where an admin in the backend can create a new Admin user. I created my own form model so I can handle the passsword. They just fill out username, nicename, email, password, select the status (active, banned, deleted), and choose a role (Root, Super, Admin). They enter the password as normal, and the custom form encrypts it. - I have checks so Root can create anything, Super can only create regular Admins, and regular admins can not create any other admins at all.

I actually had this working on my last project, but I bypassed the `isNewRecord` because I created the forms in their respective view files (create.php and update.php) instead of them both using the same `_form.php` file. It isn't a big deal, but I would like to follow the way Yii does things and get the `_form.php` file handling the forms again, if possible.

Since I am now using my own model `CreateAdminForm` instead of `Admin` model (which is a spin off of `User`), it does not have access to `isNewRecord`.

How can I get `_form.php` to use `isNewRecord` with my custom `CreateAdminForm` model?

Truncated CreateAdminForm:

```
class CreateAdminForm extends Model
{
    public $nicename;
    public $username;
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $role;
    public $status;

    public function createAdmin()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $admin = new Admin();
            $admin->nicename = $this->nicename;
            $admin->username = $this->username;
            $admin->email = $this->email;
            $admin->role = $this->role;
            $admin->status = $this->status;
            $admin->setPassword($this->password);
            $admin->generateAuthKey();
            if ($admin->save()) {
                return $admin;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

_form.php :

```
<div class="admin-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'nicename')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'role')->dropDownList(
        $model->getUserRoleDropdown(),
        ['prompt'=>' - Admin Role - ']
    ) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'status')->dropDownList(
        $model->getUserStatusDropdown(),
        ['prompt'=>' - Admin Status - ']
    ) ?>

    <?= (!$model->isNewRecord) ? Html::a('Change Password!', ['admin/change-admin-password', 'id' => $model->id]) . '<br /><br />' : '' ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Never used Yii2 yet but couldn't you just extend your Admin model instead of creating something based off that Model class?

Comment: My form is based off the already existing ContactForm and SignupForm. Just modified to fit my needs. Your suggestion may be possible. I could always grab the action to determine whether it is the create or update action, but that is a hack. Since the default create/update actions originally used `$model = Admin`, it is a plausible solution. I am working on a few other areas of the app while I wait on some more answers to come in. In a bit, I may explore that route if I don't have a solid answer here. Thank you.

Comment: You were actually right. With my current `CreateAdminForm` exactly as it is, I just changed it from extending `Model` to extend `Admin`. It works like a charm, and `isNewRecord` works. - I will give you a bit of time to write it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to make your `CreateAdminForm` class work the way you want it to work is to make it hold a copy of the `Admin` class as a property and have it work on that. That way, you could create a method that accesses Admin's `isNewRecord` property. Quick example below

```
class CreateAdminForm extends Model
{
    // This needs to be filled in with an instance of Admin. Maybe through your constructor or through dependency injection
    protected $admin;

    public function createAdmin()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $this->admin->nicename = $this->nicename;
            $this->admin->username = $this->username;
            $this->admin->email = $this->email;
            .
            .
            .
            return $this->admin->save()
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function isNewRecord()
    {
        return $this->admin->isNewRecord;
    }
}
```

As for another, more simpler way (since this seems to have answered your question), you could just have `CreateAdminForm` inherit from `Admin` to gain access to everything `ActiveRecord` and `BaseActiveRecord` such as the `getIsNewRecord()` method (and not have to worry about managing 2 objects)

```
class CreateAdminForm extends Admin
{
    // CreateAdminForm specific code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**There is no use of `isNewRecord` with `Model`**

`$isNewRecord` is a property of `ActiveRecord`, extending from `BaseActiveRecord`. So this property cannot be called when you use `Model` for your Form.

```
  class MyForm extends Model
  {

  }
```

There is no use of `isNewRecord`, since Model/Form cannot insert data into database. So, there is no chance of data Update.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. I knew there was no `isNewRecord` with model, hence my problem. The correct answer is to extend `Admin`, which does have access to it. I copied the existing use of ContactForm and SignupForm, which extend Model. I wasn't aware I could easily swap Model for Admin and it work without a hitch.